# How to process the resulting List<T> values of `groupingBy` in the same `stream()`?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

***Briefly:*** [`collect(groupingBy())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) returns a map `Map<K, List<T>>`. How can I replace , for each `K`, the value `List<T>` by a new value (of class `U`) which is computed based on `List<T>`, and return `Map<K, U>` in the *same* `stream()`?

---

***An example:*** Suppose I have a `Task`, which consists of a `taskId` and a list of `Job`s:

```
public class Task { int taskId; List<Job> jobList; }
```

For each `Job`, method `getAgentId` determines an "agent" who is able to process it:

```
// in class Job
int getAgentId() { // return the "agent" who is responsible for @param job }
```

A `Task` is partitioned into multiple sub-`Task`s such that each of them can be processed by a separate "agent":

```
// in class Partition; `Integer` for "agent" id
Map<Integer, Task> partition(Task task) { }
```

---

***My attempt:*** I used `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Integer, Task> partition(Task task) {
    int id = task.getTaskId();
    Map<Integer, List<Job>> agentJobsMap = 
        task.getJobList().stream()
                         .collect(groupingBy(Job::getAgentId),
                                  // question here);
}
```

***Question:*** However I want to return `Map<Integer, Task>` instead of `Map<Integer, List<Job>>`; that is, I want to wrap the resulting `List<Job>` of `groupingBy` into a new `Task` by `new Task(id, the resulting List<Job>)`. How to do that? Or are there alternatives without `groupingBy`?

Comment: Louis' answer using `collectingAndThen` is perfectly reasonable.  In general, though, I would avoid taking the "in the same stream" goal too far.  Chaining is nice but it can be pushed so hard that it obfuscates what's going on.  We frequently see people trying to turn two stream pipelines into being "the same stream" (by chaining off the result of a terminal operation) when it would be clearer to simply admit what is actually going on.  The goal should clarity, not "minimize the number of semicolons."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the overload of `groupingBy` that accepts another `Collector` to use on the results:

```
task.getJobList().stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
             Job::getAgentId,
             collectingAndThen(toList(), jobs -> new Task(id, jobs))));
```

Comment: Very nice code! Thank you for always being so helpful. (Just a little spelling: "job" should be "jobs"; I cannot edit it because only a single character would be added and stackoverflow complains about this.)